# Convergence of series with terms $\frac{\ln(n)}{n^2}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

So, I'm currently a TA for a calculus class, and I came across the following problem:

> Use the **limit comparison test** to determine that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\ln(n)}{n^2}$$ converges

(I'm currently grading this exact problem on an exam students have already taken). I didn't initially think this was a problem since I was thinking they could compare this series with a series whose terms are $b_n = n^{-3/2}$, but the issue is that the version of the limit comparison test that students learned in this class required having $$0< \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n} < \infty$$

so that $\sum a_n$ converges $\iff \sum b_n$ converges. I've been trying to find an appropriate choice of $b_n$ for awhile now given the strict lower bound on the limit, but I haven't had any success. Would anyone happen to have any suggestions? Is this even possible? I will say none of the students in the class of $130+$ have provided a convincing answer, and I can see the difficulty myself haha.

Comment: **Hint:**$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}^* : \sqrt n \ge \ln n \ge 0$

Comment: One could do something with the condensation test. But then the quotient does not have a limit, but the lim sup and lim inf are positive and bounded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible, take $b_n=\log(n)/n^2$, but of course this is not what you're looking for. However any other sequence that satisfies this must be of the form $C\log(n)/n^2 + o(\log(n)/n^2)$ in order to apply the LCT. So it's not possible if you're expecting another nice-looking function.

Comment: I assume you mean $o$ in place of $O$. Otherwise the leading term has the same order as the error term.

Comment: @Gary you're right! fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

$$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}^* : \sqrt n \ge \ln n \ge 0$$
Therefore:
$$\frac{1}{n^{\frac{3}{2}}} \ge \frac{\ln n}{n^2} \ge 0$$

we have : $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{\frac{3}{2}}}$ series **Riemann** convergence

Comment: The issue I have with this answer is that it's essentially using the so-called "basic comparison test" instead of a limit comparison test

Comment: @Michael I agree with your concern based on the traditional statement of the Limit Comparison Test and the directions. However, depending on the book being used for the class, sometimes this "one-sided" version of the LCT is included: see the "one-sided" section at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test